# Serverless reference variable from file cannot used twice

Tags: serverless-framework

Hi I'm implementing a custom CORS for all of my functions and I used an external file to define the CORS object.

```
service: user

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  create:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: create/bin/main
    package:
      include:
        - ./create/bin/**
    events:
      - http:
          path: user
          method: post
          cors: ${file(../../serverless-cors.yml):custom.cors}
  list:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: list/bin/main
    package:
      include:
        - ./list/bin/**
    events:
      - http:
          path: user
          method: get
          cors: ${file(../../serverless-cors.yml):custom.cors}
  show:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: show/bin/main
    package:
      include:
        - ./show/bin/**
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/{user-id}
          method: get
          cors: ${file(../../serverless-cors.yml):custom.cors}
  update:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: update/bin/main
    package:
      include:
        - ./update/bin/**
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/{user-id}
          method: post
          cors: ${file(../../serverless-cors.yml):custom.cors}
  delete:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: delete/bin/main
    package:
      include:
        - ./delete/bin/**
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/{user-id}
          method: delete
          cors: ${file(../../serverless-cors.yml):custom.cors}
```

The first reference went ok but the subsequent ones will have when I use `sls print`
`'$["functions"]["create"]["events"][0]["http"]["cors"]'`

And it resulted in failure in deploying

Is this a known issue? How can I get past this?

#### EDIT

here's the content of serverless-cors.yml

```
custom:
  cors:
    origin: '*' # <-- Specify allowed origin
    headers: # <-- Specify allowed headers
      - Content-Type
      - X-Amz-Date
      - Authorization
      - X-Api-Key
      - X-Amz-Security-Token
      - X-Amz-User-Agent
      - TZ
    allowCredentials: false
```

I also tried using a single level (`file(../../serverless-cors.yml):cors`) variable instead of two level like above with no luck

Comment: thanks interesting, does the same thing happen if you only specify by the first property for example custom? also can you show what's on the `serverless-cors.yml`?

Comment: Yes I tried that before with no luck. I did `custom.cors` because I read somewhere that your variable needs to be in custom. But maybe not for this case. I updated the question to show you the serverless-cors.yml :)

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the `serverless-cors.yml` file relative from the directory that the `serverless.yml` file is in. For example:

```
serverless.yml
path/
├──to/
└──└──serverless-cors.yml

# serverless-cors.yml
cors:
  origin: '*'
  headers:
    - Content-Type
    - X-Amz-Date
    - Authorization
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - X-Amz-User-Agent
    - TZ
  allowCredentials: false

# serverless.yml
...
events:
  - http:
      path: something
      method: post
      cors: ${file(path/to/serverless-cors.yml):cors}
```

Comment: I did that by referencing the file twice from the root yml file. the result is still the same :( the first 1 succeed but the second one always look like this `'$["functions"]["home"]["events"][0]["http"]["cors"]'`. It's the first variable which successfully refer the object.

Comment: Although I'm using `sls print` and not `sls deploy`. Does that matter?

Comment: NB: I did what you suggested by creating a `serverless.files` folder, then add `cors.yml` and reference it by `file(serverless.files/cors.yml)` from the root `serverless.yml`

Comment: It's not an error when using `sls print`. However, when deploying, it always fail because of the second reference become `'$["functions"]["home"]["events"][0]["http"]["cors"]'`, and not the object itself

Comment: If you try reference the cors in another function, what's the result of your `sls print` ?